# Returning to C++

Tags: c++, c++-cli

The last time I used C++ was before it could be managed. Recently, though, I've returned from Java to see that C++ can now be managed !

It didn't take me long to realise what `gcnew` and `^` were used for. However, I'm getting a little stuck with containers.

How can I create a container whose elements are managed classes of my own making? I'm looking for a similar container to STL `vector`.

I would like to have something like this:

```
List<MyClass ^> ^ mylist;
```

But Visual Studio returns the following errors:

```
Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error   3   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

Comment: leave this ^ and gcnew as fast as you can unless it is not to late yet and go for something normal

Comment: This is not _standard_ C++. And, fortunately, C++ is not "managed". This is some other language, probably close to C++ or derived from C++.

Comment: `gcnew` and "managed `^` pointers" are C++/CLI features. Completely different language.

Comment: Note that this is a non-standard Microsoft aberration. Stick to standard C++ unless you only ever want to work with Windows and Visual Studio.

Comment: Microsoft have got me confused adding their own ways to the world :-( they always do that.

Comment: The reason I've gone down the wrong path, then, is because I created a  Windows Form application and ended up with `public ref class` I much prefer the standard non MS approach.

Comment: I added the `managed` and `managed-c++` tags, and could not help but chuckle at the tag wiki for the latter: "Managed C++ is a **now deprecated Microsoft set of deviations** from C++..."

Comment: Make sure you compile with `/CLR`, you might also need some `using namespace System;`, etc. C++/CLI is great if you need to consume .Net assemblies or if you want to wrap C or C++ code for direct consumption in .Net applications without p/invoke. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with "native" C++ if you don't need those things.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up all. I'm going to ditch the MS way. I have been saved.

Comment: @DevSolar and I removed the managed-c++ tag because it was a very different language extension and the syntax is completely different. This is obviously is C++/CLI and should be tagged c++-cli (which I had already done).

Comment: I think `List` is located in `System::Collections::Generic` namespace, do you have `using namespace System::Collections::Generic;`?

Comment: @crashmstr: I bow to your knowledge of these murky depths. It's all the same for me: The stuff MS did to C++ that I always stayed well clear of. ;-)

Comment: I have never actually used it, but doesn't [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) support managed code for other operating systems than Windows as well?

Comment: @maddin45 Yeah but I think Mono supports only C#, not C++/CLI

Comment: @user2802841 I think that actually resolved the problem. But now there are other errors. I think I'll stick to "managed C++" for this small project, but avoid it like the bit-plague for future projects.

Comment: C++/CLI is one of the best tools for writing interop glue between native and managed code. It's not a great choice for other purposes.

Comment: In the end I split my solution into two parts: A mainly CLR project, with just a little unmanaged code, and a separate DLL which is purely unmanaged C++. This resolved all conflicts and the two work together nicely now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The last time I used C++ was before it could be managed. Recently, though, I've returned from Java to see that C++ can now be managed !

C++ cannot "be managed". You are looking here at three languages:

1. C++ (which you are coming back to).
2. Managed C++ (MC++) - this was the first version of the C++ altered by Microsoft into a new language, capable to work with both native code (normal C++) and the .NET platform (managed). This has been deprecated by Microsoft and replaced with C++/CX. As such, DO NOT WRITE MC++ code.
3. C++/CX - this is the latest version of C++ altered by Microsoft for .NET interoperability. Use it when you need to write code interacting with both managed (that is, hosted/running under the .NET runtime) and un-managed code.

Either way, for your code to compile, you need a compiler switch enabling managed code (`/CLR`) and the following changes:

- define your class as a C++/CX class (using ref keyword).
- import the list from collections (you will be effectively using the .NET collections)
- allocate everything with `ref new` (similar to Java and .NET).

That said, unless you are writing interop code between managed and unmanaged code using the MS .NET plarform, do not go with C++/CLI. Use C++ for unmanaged code, and C# or VB for managed code. You will be subjected to less headaches this way.

Comment: I originally created a CLI windows forms app which is great for getting a GUI based application running quickly, but i ran into problems with mixing managed and unmanaged code. How can i switch between te two?

Comment: I think the easiest would be to write three different libraries (client native C++ code, .NET GUI code and C++/CLI for iterop between the two). This implies splitting your VS solution between three projects. I am not sure if this is the best practice though. It's been three years since I last touched the .NET platform.

Comment: This answer is mostly good, but you seem to be confusing C++/CLI (for .Net, GC-based) and C++/CX (its spinoff for Windows Store/Windows Phone apps, COM-refcount-based).

Comment: @pbs For the most part, "It Just Works". Please post other questions for specific problems you run into.

Comment: Surprisingly, `ref` is not a C++/CLI keyword. It's some characters in several "spaced keywords," such as `ref class`. And, of course, `ref` is still usable as an identifier.